# Trouble With Four Column Layout CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble putting it into words. So as an example, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://appono.tumblr.com

Now, in words:
I want to have a four column layout with divs that vary in height. In the example above, the divs all have the same width, but their height varies, and the divs can fill in the gaps with no problem. However, I tried to accomplish this with simple floats to the left and failed:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ha32Q/

The HTML (random sloppy example)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="smexy">
            <h3>ASD SADA N SAD AD AS D ASD A SD ADWW AD W AD AS Ds D WD D AWD W D WAD AW AD WA D SADAS F AFW A F WAF AS F</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="smexy">
            <h3>Why Hello</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="smexy">
            <h3>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR I AM TYPIING THIS FROM MEMORY OKAY THANKS GOODBYE HAVE A NICE DAY</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="smexy">
            <p>Lolwut</p>
        </div>
        <div class="smexy">
            <h3>Yo WHY HELLO DAR</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.smexy {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    background:#d2d2d2;
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

How can I accomplish what it is I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it CSS only, you need javascript.

And it seems that a good library that does it for you is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

In your case, use something like

```
var container = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.smexy'
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha32Q/1/)

See the [list of options](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html) to achieve your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the effect as the site your just shared, use the plug-in they used. :)
What you're trying to accomplish can't be done with straight up CSS. Floating doesn't work that way - unless you create 3 `.content` columns and loaded your `.smexy` DIVs in the columns. Think more vertical versus horizontal. You dig? :)

Here's the plug-in:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Then look at this sexiness (smexy-ness?):
http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html